# Bubblesort-like algorithm. What is the worst-case time complexity?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I made a sorting algorithm using the same kind of logic of the heapify algorithm. However, I do not believe this is heap sort. The logic of it, is that I compare two pieces of an array (Initially was going to be a double linked list, but java would not allow me to do that without making my own class) with the one next to it. If it is larger, swap. Much like a bubble sort. However, when the swap is completed, I then do a reverse bubble sort on the second element, to maintain the order of the array.

I'm not entirely sure of the worst case time complexity of this, but I think it is O(n^2). What is the time complexity of this, and also, what sorting algorithm does it most look like?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * firstNum and secondNum trade places.
 * Whenever a swap is done, sink the secondNumber
 */
private static void swap(int[] A, int firstNum, int secondNum) {
    int temp = A[secondNum];

    A[secondNum] = A[firstNum];
    A[firstNum] = temp;

    sink(A, firstNum);
}

/**
 * Swap places upward until condition is false.
 */
private static void rise(int[] A, int currIndex) {

    int nextIndex = currIndex + 1;

    if (nextIndex <= A.length - 1 && A[currIndex] > A[nextIndex]) {

        swap(A, currIndex, nextIndex);
        rise(A, nextIndex);
    }
}

/**
 * Swap places downward until condition is not met.
 */
private static void sink(int[] A, int currIndex) {

    int prevIndex = currIndex - 1;

    if (currIndex > 0 &&  A[currIndex] < A[currIndex - 1]) {
        swap(A, prevIndex, currIndex);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] values = {4, 7, 2, 1, 3, 5, 100, 0};

    for (int i = 0; i < values.length - 1; i++) {
        rise(values, i);
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(values));


}
```

}

Comment: What exactly is your question? To calculate its time complexity?

Comment: @user202729 that, and what the name of the sorting algorithm is, if anyone knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say this is insertion sort in disguise. It thus has worst case and average complexity of O(n^2).

To see this, first realize that the recursive call to `rise` in the `rise` method is redundant: the element being raised there will be reached anyway by a later call to `rise` from the outer loop in the `main` method.
What's left is recursive calls to `sink` from the `swap` method for every element in the list. What that does is to place every element into the right position in the already sorted initial bit of the list: this is essentially insertion sort.